# Why is ON DUPLICATE KEY not working as expected?

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

Before I start, I'm not a web developer by trade. I'm self taught using google and [StackOverflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com).

So I recently moved my site from a shared hosting to a VPS.

My provider moved my site / files over to my new hosting. Both run cPanel.

I had a script which worked perfectly fine on my old hosting-

```
INSERT INTO `database`.`table`
    (`UUID`, `UpdateDate`, `JoinDate`) 
VALUES 
    ('$uuid',NOW(),NOW())
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   `UpdateDate` = NOW()
```

The problem is it doesnt work any more on my new server.

The problem *i think* is it doesnt update or insert due to not updating all the columns in that table.

I created two test tables, Table A with the 3 columns in above UUID, UpdateDate, JoinDate
and a second
Table B with 4 columns in UUID, Username, UpdateDate, JoinDate.

UUID is both Unique and Primary in both tables.

Table A - This table works as expected.
[image: Table A - This table works as expected]

Table B - This table doesnt insert/update due to the extra column Username.
[image: Table B - This doesnt work as it has an extra column named Username]

Any idea why this query doesn't work with table B? Do you have to insert/update every table column when running the query? Is it a PHP settings I need to change on my hosting?

Sorry if I haven't provided all information, this is my first DBSE question.

```
CREATE TABLE TestUserA` 
( UUID varchar(40) NOT NULL, 
  UpdateDate datetime NOT NULL, 
  JoinDate datetime NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

ALTER TABLE TestUser 
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (UUID), 
  ADD UNIQUE KEY UUID (UUID), 
  ADD KEY UUID_2 (UUID);
```

- Server type: MariaDB Server version: 10.2.14-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
- Protocol version: 10 cpsrvd 11.68.0.36
- Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73
- PHP extension: mysqli
- PHP version: 5.6.30

Comment: *CREATE TABLE TestUserA* Add DEFAULT / ON UPDATE modificators to datetime fields - and You do not need in ODKU, simple INSERT IGNORE enough.  *ALTER TABLE TestUser* You make 3 copies of index. WTF? *Any idea why this query doesn't work with table B?* Enable PHP errors output - and You will SEE errors instead of guess them.

Comment: To elaborate on what @Akina is saying:  A PK is a `UNIQUE KEY` and a `UNIQUE KEY` is a key.  Don't create redundant keys.

Comment: What version of MySQL/MariaDB was on the previous server?  Current is MariaDB 10.2.14?  There may have been changes to the system default settings.

Answer (score 5):

> Any idea why this query doesn't work with table B? Do you have to insert/update every table column when running the query?

Yes, `UserName` is a `NOT NULL` column and doesn't have a `DEFAULT` value. Therefore you need to provide a value for every row `INSERT`. Not for `UPDATE` though, the column can be updated or not, depending on your requirements.

> Is it a PHP settings I need to change on my hosting?

No, nothing to do with PHP.

> I had a script which worked perfectly fine on my old hosting ...

If the script was working perfectly in the previous server, **when inserting in either table**, then the tables were not transferred identically. The extra columns - besides the 3 that the script provides values for - would have been defined as `NULL` (so they'd have a `DEFAULT NULL`) or there might be a `DEFAULT` attribute defined when the table was created.

Another possibility - besides lack of `DEFAULT` attribute - is that the table had an `INSERT` trigger that supplied a value for the `UserName` automatically upon insert and that the triggers were not properly copied when the the database was transfered.

Comment: Hi @ypercube. I actually tweeted you earlier regarding this.

I checked the box for NULL in the username field and ran my query again and it worked first time. 

https://i.imgur.com/rz3A9rF.png

Although on my old server it never used to say NULL in the blank username box, it would just be blank.

I feel like such an idiot.

Comment: Is there any setting i can enable to allow all DB fields to be blank.

Comment: @Bonxy - a `VARCHAR` column is always _allowed_ to be blank.  To have it _default to_ blank requires `DEFAULT ('')` in the `CREATE TABLE`.